Expression replacement with Wildcard variable only works in isolation
I am trying to replace a subexpression. There are many questions on this topic, but I've found that using a wildcard variable as a multiplier seems to work in isolation but not when there are extra terms. For example:
import sympy as smp

x, y, z, a = smp.symbols("x y z a")
b = smp.Wild("b")

expr_1 = x/a**2 + y/a**2 + z/a**2
replacement = b*x + b*y + b*z
replaced = expr_1.replace(replacement, b)  # essentially, I am saying that x + y + z = 1

That example works and the result is 1/a**2. But if I add an extra part, the replacement won't work.
expr_2 = expr_1 + 20/a
not_replaced = expr_2.replace(replacement, b)

The result not_replaced is the same as expr_2.
Is this behavior expected? Is there a way to achieve the desired result using .replace with a wildcard variable like I've tried?

(expr1 + 20/a) is evaluated into one subexpression. That's is why it does not match b*x+b*y+b*z. To prevent (expr1+20/a) from being evaluated into one subexpression try expr2=smp.Add(expr1, 20/a, evaluate=False).

@user202311 While that might work, that addition was more of just a way to generate expr_2 for this example. In reality, expr_2 was generated from some other operations and the result is something similar to what I show (namely, it has a subexpression I want to replace and then there are some extra terms that I want ignored during the replacement).

Assuming expo_2 is an Add expression with replacement being one of its addends would the following helpc = smp.Wild("c"); expr_2.match(replacement+c)[b] + expr_2.match(replacement+c)[c]?

Try an algebraic replacement:

solve the desired relationship (x+y+z=1) for a variable `x=1-y-z'
do the substitution
solve the relationship for any variable that still exists when you are done (if any) and solve the desired relationship for that variable
do the final substitution


or
rel = Eq(x+y+z,1);
eq = expr_2 + x
rep=solve(rel, (eq.free_symbols & rel.free_symbols), dict=True)[0]
new=eq.subs(rep).expand()
per=solve(rel, new.free_symbols & rel.free_symbols, dict=True)[0]
new.subs(per).expand()

gives
x + 20/a + a**(-2)

